# getContentResolver().insert(Uri,values) returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am calling the insert function in WordListActivity.java from MainActivity.java has the below code by sending the data that needs to be inserted in database.
getContentResolver().insert gives error.

I have also provided the provider permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.personaldictionary.adapter.DictionaryAdapter;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryContract;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryDbHelper;
import com.example.personaldictionary.utils.NetworkUtils;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;


    private CardView mCardView;
    private TextView mWordText;
    private TextView mWordDef;
    private TextView mWordEtylo;



    private DictionaryDbHelper mDbHelper;

    WordListActivity wordListActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        wordListActivity = new WordListActivity();



        mCardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.word_card);
        mCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mWordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word_text);
        mWordDef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word_definition);
        mWordEtylo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word_etymologies);

        mDbHelper = new DictionaryDbHelper(this);
        mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        mCardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG," insertWord called: ");

                wordListActivity.insertWord(mWordText.getText().toString(),mWordDef.getText().toString(),mWordEtylo.getText().toString());

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

WordListActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.personaldictionary.adapter.DictionaryAdapter;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryContract;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryDbHelper;

public class WordListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "WordListActivity";

    DictionaryAdapter mAdapter;
    DictionaryDbHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_list);

        RecyclerView word_rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.word_rv);
        word_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mDbHelper = new DictionaryDbHelper(this);

        mAdapter = new DictionaryAdapter(this,getAllItems());
        word_rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    }


    public void insertWord(String word,String word_def,String word_etylo){


        Uri newUri = null;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertWord() word: "+word+" word_def: "+word_def+" word_et: "+word_etylo);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD,word);
        values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION,word_def);
        values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ETYMOLOGIES,word_etylo);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI: "+DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"values: "+values);

        newUri = getContentResolver().insert(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);


        mAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());

        if (newUri == null) {
            Toast.makeText(WordListActivity.this, "Word insert error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(WordListActivity.this, "Word insert Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private Cursor getAllItems(){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getAllItems inside");
         String[] projection = {DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry._ID,
                 DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD,
                 DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION,
                 DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ETYMOLOGIES};

         return getContentResolver().query(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
    }

}
```

DictionaryProvider.java

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {


    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DictionaryProvider";

    public DictionaryDbHelper mDbHelper;
    /** URI matcher code for the content URI for the dictionary table */
    private static final int WORDS = 100;

    /** URI matcher code for the content URI for a single word in the dictionary table */
    private static final int WORD_ID = 101;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onCreate called");
        mDbHelper = new DictionaryDbHelper(getContext());

        return true;
    }

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static{
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"sUriMatcher called");
        sUriMatcher.addURI(DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, DictionaryEntry.PATH_WORDS, WORDS);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, DictionaryEntry.PATH_WORDS+"/#",WORD_ID);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"query called");
        SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor;

        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"query match: "+match);
        switch(match){
            case WORDS:

                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"match WORDS");

                cursor = database.query(DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null,null);
                break;
            case WORD_ID:

                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"match WORD_ID");
                selection = DictionaryEntry._ID+"=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};

                cursor = database.query(DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder,null);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown Uri "+uri);
        }

        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getType");
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getType match: "+match);
        switch (match) {
            case WORDS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"return ProductEntry.CONTENT_LIST_TYPE");
                return DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_LIST_TYPE;
            case WORD_ID:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"return ProductEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE");
                return DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown URI " + uri + " with match " + match);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insert uri "+ uri +" values: "+values);

        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insert match: "+match);

        switch(match){
            case WORDS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertDictionary");
                return insertDictionary(uri, values);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported for "+uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete uri:"+ uri+" selection: "+selection+"selectionArgs: "+selectionArgs);
        // Get writeable database
        SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // Track the number of rows that were deleted
        int rowsDeleted;

        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete match:"+ match);
        switch (match) {
            case WORDS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete WORDS");
                // Delete all rows that match the selection and selection args
                rowsDeleted = database.delete(DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case WORD_ID:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete WORD_ID");
                // Delete a single row given by the ID in the URI
                selection = DictionaryEntry._ID + "=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };
                rowsDeleted = database.delete(DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Deletion is not supported for " + uri);
        }
        // If 1 or more rows were deleted, then notify all listeners that the data at the
        // given URI has changed
        if (rowsDeleted != 0) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete rowsDeleted != 0");
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }

        // Return the number of rows deleted
        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"update uri: "+uri+" values: "+ values+" selection: "+ selection+" selectionArgs: "+selectionArgs);
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"update match: "+match);
        switch (match){
            case WORDS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"update WORDS");
                return updateDictionary(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            case WORD_ID:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"update WORD_ID");
                selection = DictionaryEntry._ID+"=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
                return updateDictionary(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Update is not supported for "+uri);

        }
    }


    private Uri insertDictionary(Uri uri, ContentValues values){

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertDictionary uri: "+uri+" values: "+values);

        String word = values.getAsString(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertDictionary word: "+word);
        if (word == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dictionary requires a word");
        }

        String word_def_1 = values.getAsString(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertDictionary word_def_1: "+word_def_1);
        if (word_def_1 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dictionary requires a word definition");
        }


        String etymologies = values.getAsString(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ETYMOLOGIES);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertDictionary etymologies: "+etymologies);

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long id = db.insert(DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertDictionary() id "+id);

        if(id==-1){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Failed to insert row for "+uri);

            return null;
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,id): "+ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,id));
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,id);
    }

    private int updateDictionary(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs){


        if (values.containsKey(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD)) {
            String word = values.getAsString(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD);
            if (word == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dictionary requires a word");
            }
        }

        if (values.containsKey(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION)) {
            // Check that the price is greater than or equal to 0 Rs
            String word_def_1 = values.getAsString(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION);
            if (word_def_1 == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dictionary requires a word definition");
            }
        }



        // If there are no values to update, then don't try to update the database
        if (values.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        int rowsUpdated = database.update(DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);

        // If 1 or more rows were updated, then notify all listeners that the data at the
        // given URI has changed
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"updateDictionary rowsUpdated: "+rowsUpdated);
        if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        }

        return rowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

Error Logs:

```
2020-06-14 18:55:15.948 24271-24271/com.example.personaldictionary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.personaldictionary, PID: 24271
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:101)
        at com.example.personaldictionary.WordListActivity.insertWord(WordListActivity.java:68)
        at com.example.personaldictionary.MainActivity$2.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:110)
        at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:6685)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6643)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6661)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:25862)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: `wordListActivity = new WordListActivity()` -- **never** create an instance of an activity yourself.

Comment: The error tells it all. You call .getContenrResolver() on a null object. So getContext() returned null.

Comment: Each activity has its own instance so you need to use `getContenrResolver()` in the `MainActivity` 
you can not create an instance for an activity like this `new WordListActivity()` the activity created by the system we should not use `new`